# Reactjs - Update state of parent after obtaining calculated value from another component function

Tags: reactjs

In my React App, I have a text box where users can type location in a Google Autocomplete box - `LocationInput`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
...
import LocationInput from './location-input'
...


change = (what, e) => this.setState({ [what]: e.target.value })
....
      render() {
        let {
          location,
          country,
      ...
    } = this.state

...
...
<LocationInput value={location} change={this.change} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just have the change function work like:

```
change = location => this.setState({ location })
....
render() {
   return <LocationInput value={this.state.location} change={this.change} />
}
```

and then in the child

```
const LocationInput = ({ value, change }) => {
  return (
  <div className="edit_location_div">
    <Autocomplete
        className="locationInput my2"
        onPlaceSelected={ place => {
          change(getDistrict(place))
        }}
        placeholder="Enter Nearest MAJOR City"
    />
  </div>
  )
}
```

of course I am making the assumption that the "onPlaceSelected" returns the same data-type as the one stored in the state.

Answer (score 2):

You pass the new location to the `change` handler:

```
    onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
      change(getDistrict(place))
    }}
```

This will call the change function in the outer component and update the state. It shouldn't cause an infinite loop unless for some reason `onPlaceSelected` gets called again automatically.